# Using Python or TypeScript to transform text that I select in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

Let's say I select some text in the editor.  I would like to define my own Python functions or scripts that:

1. Take as an input the selected text as a string.
2. Transform it and return a new string that replaces the selected text back in the editor

Moreover, I would like to ideally register these functions or scripts as a VSCode commands (with a specific `commandID`s) that I can define myself and to the command palette in VSCode. By doing so, I can bind them to a shortcut in `keybindings.json` with specific shortcuts and when clauses.

---

Is there any built-in functionality in VSCode to do this? If not, what set of steps can I follow to do it?

Comment: I think you need to write a TypeScript wrapper for your python script to get the text and run your python script, then replace the text with output from your script. Tasks in VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Let's say my question asks for the exact same thing, but using TypeSript functions / scripts, instead of Python ones. In that case, I suppose I wouldn't need to write a TypeScript wrapper (of my Python code). Would that change your recommended course of action? (e.g. using tasks?)

Comment: No problem. Yes, I think it makes more sense to just use TypeScript and create a task for vscode.

Comment: Snippets can generally do what you ask unless it is very complicated.  Attach an example to your question of before and after.

Comment: Unless your transform actually involves running python.

Comment: Thanks @Mark - I actually want to run my own Python functions on the input string to generate a new one. I come from Emacs and have too many scenarios to list, from formatting numbers and text, to postprocessing text that I paste in the editor to "LaTeXify it", to expanding my own set of macros or keywords across the selected text. There is a _large world of options_ that opens up if I can easily keyboard bind a Python function of my choice that receives selected text as an input and optionally writes back to the editor or to the clipboard (w/o  modifying the selected text in this last case)

Comment: I have written an extension, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform,  wherein you can write javascript (with the vscode extension api if you wish) to replace selected text.  You can create these methods such tthat they wil l individually appear in the Command Palette and can have keybindings set to them.  No python though.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69197859/836330.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: We are the author of vscode-texty extension*

Based on [OP's suggestion](https://github.com/datasert/vscode-texty/issues/1), we have enhanced the [vscode-texty](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=datasert.vscode-texty) to add this support.

Now it supports following capabilities.

- Select some text and process selection using adhoc script
- Select some text and process line within selection using adhoc script
- Custom script can refer to lodash, numeral and moment libraries for easy manipulation of text
- Save the script as custom command and invoke that command with quick pick options
- Key bind that custom command for quick execution

One issue (due to limitation of vscode api) is that, custom commands does not appear in the standard command palette. So to invoke via UI, you first invoke command `Texty: Process selections using custom command`, which shows all available commands as quick pick options, executes the selection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible, but I'm unaware of any extension that currently supports this idea. You will probably need to write your extension to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[scriptbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cubicle6.scriptbox) allow you to write a js function to modify your selected text, but could not registry as a command