# VS Code: Is there an extension that allows me to run random scripts and pipe their output back into vscode at the current cursor position?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The title pretty much covers my question.

Is there an extension that allows me to run random scripts and pipe their output back into VS Code at the current cursor position?

Let's say I have a markdown file:

```
Lalala

<CURSOR_HERE>
```

Then, with my cursor at the respective position, I can activate this extension/task/? to run a specific script, grab its output, and paste it at the cursor position.

I tried googling but I couldn't find anything.

The closest I found was Tasks, but the API doesn't seem to allow capturing and piping output back into VSCode.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Have a look at the oddly named `Filter Text` extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yhirose.FilterText

Comment: Hey, that does that cover my needs! Can u make a reply so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Filter Text](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yhirose.FilterText) extension will do what you want.  Apparently the name derives from the ability to select text, transform it then replace it - like sorting the selected text.

But you don't have to select anything and then the result of the supplied script (shell command) will be inserted at the cursor position.

Examples from the README:

```
"filterText.commandList": [     // in settings.json
    {
        "name": "Sort unique",
        "description": "Sorts and find the unique entries",
        "command": "sort | uniq"
    },
    {
        "name": "Columnize CSV",
        "description": "Columnize comma separated values",
        "command": "column -s \",\" -t"
    },
    {
        "name": "XML lint",
        "description": "Run the command through xmllint",
        "command": "xmllint --format -"
    }
]
```

Then match a keybinding to one of those "commands":

```
{
    "key": "shift+alt+l",                     // in keybindings.json
    "command": "extension.filterTextInplace",
    "args": { "cmd": "Sort unique" }
}
```